# Html to DataTable -> Loop all rows of table instead of looping the ones only in the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, datatable

I have a datatable like below in my asp.net-4.5 page:

```
Name   City   Value  Action
A       B      10    delete
X       Y      10    delete
T       R      10    delete
ALL    ALL     30
```

An HTML table is converted into such a datatable via `$(#example).datatable()`

When the "Delete" link is clicked, the regarding row is being deleted and the value of the row including ALL is being updated in javascript. So here, if I remove the first row, the table will be like below WITHOUT any page refresh.

```
Name   City   Value  Action
X       Y      10    delete
T       R      10    delete
ALL    ALL     20
```

One issue here is that the row having ALL TOTAL can be anywhere else, it is not always at the end of the table. The user can re-sort the table by clicking a column. For example, if Value column is clicked, the row including ALL will be the first row.

At this point, I want to locate where the row is located. To do that I have a for loop like below:

```
for (var i = 0, r; r = document.getElementById("example").rows[i]; i++) {
    if ($('#example').find("tr:eq(" + i + ")").find("td:eq(2)").html() == 'ALL') {
       locateALLrow = i;
       break;
   }
}
```

This for loop above works perfectly, **when there is 1 page of data only (One page includes 10 rows).** So my questions:

1 - How I can traverse the other rows located in other pages as well? This loop above only works for the first 10 rows and stops. How can I extend it to all table?

2- Is there a better way to locate the index of the row including ALL (as Name column).

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Tried the loop like below, didn't fix:

```
for (var i = 0; i<document.getElementById("example").getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++) 
{...}
```

Comment: You can use datatable footer, which will maintain Total at the bottom in common for all pages. Refer https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Answer (score 0):

*1 - How I can traverse the other rows located in other pages as well? This loop above only works for the first 10 rows and stops. How can I extend it to all table?*

Instead of traversing the html table which shows only first n rows data when using pagination, try working with the **datatable API**. You'll be able to loop through complete data with that.
https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()

*2- Is there a better way to locate the index of the row including ALL (as Name column).*

Same as above.Use **datatable API** instead of looping through current html shown data.